# How To build MySql Query to Get Call History from Database

Tags: mysql, date, range

I am newly hire intern in web development field and my senior ask me to build mysql query to draw out call history from database.

They want me to build query to get call record of:
1- Today
2- Yesterday
3- Last Week
4- this week

Just give me sample code or give me hint. we are working on mobile billing app. Please help me it is very necessary for me because i am a fresh intern. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your hint is the sql keyword "between".

Comment: Bro can you just give me one real world example..?

Answer (score 0):

```
select fname, lname, tCalled, date from calls where date between now() and now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

if I am thinking right. I didn't test this